# Why my activity can't import DaoMaster.java gennerated by greendao

Tags: greendao

I created by [this post](http://blog.gaku.net/how-to-integrate-greendao-to-an-android-studio-project/),I genarate the Entity,Dao,DaoMaster and DaoSession ,but I can't import these class?
How can I do this?My android project has a java module in android studio,I generated the src-gem in my android project,and I can't add the src folder as java sources folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build.gradle

```
android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src-gem']
        }
    }
}
```

It's work.

Answer (score 0):

For GreenDao 3 add this to android section of app's gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/greendao']
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the Entity, Dao, DaoMaster and DaoSession were generated.
Add the below code into build.gradle of your project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.paduy.greendaoforandroidstudio"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
}
```

[Reference link](http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/)

Answer (score -1):

**In my case it's work**

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

android { .....  }

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
    targetGenDir 'src/main/java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/greendao']
    }
}

dependencies {
       .............
       .............
compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
}
```